# Checking if my solution to this double integral is correct

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Is it it

$\int_0^t \left ( \int_v^t S(u)du \right ) \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$ =

$\int_0^t  \frac{\left ( { S(t^2)- S(v^2) }\right )}{2}\alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

$\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( { S(t^2)}\right )}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$ - $\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( {S(v^2) }\right )}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

$\frac{\left ( { S(t^2)}\right )}{2}\int_0^t     \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$ - $\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( { S(v^2) }\right )}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

or

$\int_0^t  \frac{\left ( { S(t)- S(v^2) }\right )}{2}\alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

$\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( { S(t)}\right )^2}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$ - $\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( {S(v) }\right )^2}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

$\frac{\left ( { S(t)}\right )^2}{2}\int_0^t     \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$ - $\int_0^t   \frac{\left ( { S(v) }\right )^2}{2}  \alpha(v)\lambda(v)dv$

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong or missing any steps.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! I am not correcting you, but asking: how do you know that $\int_v^tS(u)du=\frac{S(t^2)-S(v^2)}2$?

Comment: @manooooh, I dont, I am guessing

Comment: An intelligent guess can be a start but what was that particular guess based on?  You surely must know that $\int_v^t u^2 du= \frac{t^3- v^3}{3}$?

Comment: @user247327, yes, so it is s(t)^2 or s(t^2) ?

Comment: It is **neither**!  It is F(t^2)- F(v^2) where "F" is an anti-derivative of S.  And that depends strongly on what "S" is!

Comment: @user247327, S(t) = { 1.2, 2.3, 3.6, 4.1...} vector of values at time t, {1, 4, 8, 23..}